# Creating a line between one paragraph and the next

Tags: formatting, paragraphs

I just want to make it such that there is a line between my current and my next paragraph but also to have no indentation on the second paragraph.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi ! Could you provide us your code (MWE : http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe)

Comment: If you want it for *all* paragraphs, just set the length `\parskip`.  If it is a one-off, you could add a `~\par\noindent` before the 2nd paragraph text.

Comment: The second half doesn't seem like a new pararaph so I would not leave a blank line, just use `\\[\baselineskip]` to force the line break and leave vertical space before the next line,

Comment: by "line" do you mean a blank line or a rule?

Comment: I mean a blank line.